# Executing more than two SELECT statements with java JDBC not generating complete resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a block of code for java JDBC to execute two select statements. It works as expected. It fetches two different records. Both records have a different number of rows and I can verify this in the console that both queries execute correctly. The issue is that I added a third query. It executes but somehow, in console, the third query is showing the resultset for the second query. I checked in DB manually, query one and two pulled the correct number of rows, but query three is pulling the same record as query two. I am not sure what I have done wrong

```
    String sql = "";
    String sql2 = "";
    String sql3 = "";
    String driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:db2://ip:port/DBNAME";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    int count = 0;
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Result row count of query number one is: " + count);
    count = 0;
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql2);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Result row count of query number two is: " + count);
```

This is the third query I added:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql3);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Result row count of query number three is: " + count);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `count = 0;` before executing the third query.

Comment: Fantastic, @Alfredo. It works. Somehow I missed the `count = 0;` What is the cleanest way to print all the strings from all the rows for the three queries? If you can add this to the answer, plus one.